# A short question about the convexity of a function

Tags: probability, convex-analysis

Let $x$ and $y$ be two numbers; $0\leq x \leq 1$ and $0\leq y \leq 1$ satisfying
$$\mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{Y}=\left\{(x,y):\sum^{\lfloor k\rfloor}_{i=0}\binom{n}{i}(1-y)^{i} y^{n-i} +\sum^{\lfloor k\rfloor}_{i=0}\binom{n}{i}x^i (1-x)^{n-i}=1\right\}$$

Define a function $f^n_k:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ with the mapping $\mathcal{X} \overset{f^n_k}{\mapsto} \mathcal{Y}$

> Prove that for every $k<n/2$, the function $f_k^n$ is concave (or similarly for every $k>n/2$ the function $f_k^n$ is convex).

For simplicity, $n$ can be assumed odd.

---

**Summary of what I've found (for $k<n/2$):**

$f_k^n$ is obviously continous and passes through $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$.

$f_k^n$ passes through all pairs $(x,y)$ for which $y>x$ holds (except at $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$, therefore $f_k^n$ lies above $y=x$ line on $[0,1]^2$.

For every $f_k^n(x_0)=y_0$ there is an $\epsilon>0$ close point to $x_0$, namely $x_0+\epsilon$ such that $f_k^n(x_0+\epsilon)=y_0+\delta$ for some positive $\delta$.

This proves that $f_k^n$ is increasing above $y=x$ line, but I dont think that it is enough for concavity.

Here is the figure for $n=5$:[image]

**Details of what I've done:**

The set defined above is the same with

$$\mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{Y}=\left\{(x,y): B(k,n,1-y)=1-B(k,n,x)\right\}$$

where $B$ is the binomial c.d.f.

Now let $h_0(x;n,k)=1-B(k,n,x)$ and $h_1(y;n,k)=B(k,n,1-y)$. I am able to prove that both $h_0$ and $h_1$ are increasing functions of $x$ and $y$ respectively.

I know that in case $k=n/2$ then  $$h_0(x;n,n/2)=h_1(x;n,n/2)$$

One can see that we also have the following inequalities:

$$h_0(x;n,n/2-1)>h_0(x;n,n/2)$$
and
$$h_1(x;n,n/2-1)<h_1(x;n,n/2)$$
From this point i conclude that 
$$h_0(x;n,n/2-1)>h_1(x;n,n/2-1)\quad\forall x\quad\quad (1)$$
BUT the condition of the set says that I need to find all $(x,y)$ such that $$h_0(x;n,n/2-1)=h_1(y;n,n/2-1)\quad\quad (2)$$

If $x=y$ or $x>y$ is assumed to satisfy $(2)$ then this is a contradiction for $(1)$. Accordingly I conclude that $y>x$ must be true for all pairs $(x,y)\in[0,1]^2$ except $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$, which always satisfy the equality $(2)$.

In the next step I assume the point $(x_0,y_0)$ is valid and satisfies $(2)$. Then II choose another point which is very close to $x_0$, i.e., $x_0+\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$. Then since $h_0$ is an increasing function of $x$ then I will have $$h_0(x_0+\epsilon;n,n/2-1)>h_0(x_0;n,n/2-1)$$

this says that left hand side of $(2)$ increased with adding $\epsilon$ to $x_0$ and for $(2)$ to hold, right hand side must also increase. We are lucky because $h_1$ is also an increasing function of $y$ therefore if $(x_0,y_0)$ is a valid point satisfying $(2)$, then $(x_0+\epsilon,y_0+\delta)$ should also be valid for some positive $\delta$.

I used $h_0(x;n,n/2-1)$ for the case $k<n/2$ but I could use $h_0(x;n,n/2-a)$ for some $a$. The conclusion would not change.

**Thanks:**

Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you define "short question"? :)

Comment: @LiuGang ahahaha very nice comment. Only the question is short of course)) my efforts is huge but it seems still I need a bit more to get concaveness.

Comment: Just to understand your question. Do you mean the function $f_k^n$ is implicitly defined by $\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}$? So you mean for each $x$, there is a unique $y$ such that $(x,y) \in \mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}$?

Comment: @LiuGang yes exactly. $f_k^n$ is the function that connects all $(x,y)$ that satisfies the given condition in the set. Plus it is defined from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$. Can one make a better definition for $f_k^n$? This was my best trial to be honest.

Comment: Hint: You can rewrite the second sum as being from $n-k$ to $n$. If you set $x=y$, the equality to $1$ is achieved when $k=n/2$. When $k<n/2$, there are missing terms which must be compensated by a larger $y$, and conversely, when $k>n/2$, there is an overlap in the terms which must be compensated by a smaller $y$

Comment: @YvesDaoust thanks for the comment. My own work is very similar to this. It is long though. Could you have a look at?

Comment: I think I got a quite nice proof based on the properties of involutive maps, Fenchel's inequality was inspiring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$ g(n,k,x)=\sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{n}{j}x^j(1-x)^{n-j}. $$
Assuming that $n$ is odd and $k<\frac{n}{2}$, and taking, for short, $g(x)=g(n,k,x)$, we just have to prove that
$$ g^{-1}(1-g(1-x)) $$
is a convex function on $[0,1]$. This is equivalent to proving that
$$ h(x)=g^{-1}(1-g(x)) $$
is a convex function on the same interval.

$h(x)$ has an interesting property: it is an involutive map, since $h(h(x))=x$. Moreover, since $g$ is decreasing, we have that $1-g$ is increasing while $g^{-1}$ is decreasing, so $h$ is decreasing. By differentiation we have:

$$h'(x)\, h'(h(x)) = 1, $$
$$ h''(x)\, h'(h(x)) + h'(x)^2 h''(h(x)) = 0, $$
$$ h''(x)+h'(x)^3 h''(h(x)) = 0, $$
$$ h''(h(x)) + h'(h(x))^3 h''(x) = 0,$$
$$ \frac{h''(h(x))}{h''(x)} = -\frac{1}{h'(x)^3} \geq 0. \tag{1}$$

so the convexity/concavity of $h(x)$ over $[0,1]$ just depends on the convexity/concavity of $h(x)$ in a small neighbourhood of $1$, i.e. on the behaviour of $g$ in a small neighbourhood of $x=0$. Since $g(n,k,x)$ behaves like $1-\binom{n}{k+1}x^{k+1}$ in a neighbourhood of zero, we have that $h(x)$ is convex in a neighbourhood of $1$, so it is convex on $[0,1]$ due to $(1)$.

Comment: I didnt understand two points: 1. how to reduce the problem to just showing that $g^{-1}(1-g(1-x))$ is convex? The original problem appears to be on $(x,y):g(x)+g(1-y)=1$. 2. how is $h(h(x))=x$

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören: For the first question, notice that by the binomial theorem it happens that $g(n,k,1-x)=1-g(n,n-k-1,x)$ and $y$ is defined as the solution of $g(n,k,x)+g(n,k,1-y)=1$. For the second question, just compute $h(h(x))$ once you know that $h(x)=g^{-1}(1-g(x))$. You'll simply get $h(h(x))=x$.

Comment: Jack, sorry it is probably a bit late but I am trying understand the conclusion of your answer and I am confused in the last parts. Until $(1)$, everything is okay. First, why should $(1)$ imply that if $h(x)$ in a small neighborhood of $1$ is convex, then $h(x)$ is convex on $[0,1]$? I understood $h(x)$ around $1$ is the same with $g$ around $0$. Then $g$ is concave around $0$, so $f=1-g$ is convex, which is fine. Then, $h=g^{-1}(f)$ is convex but how? Is it true that decreasing function of a convex function is convex? Could you please help me understand these two points? thanks in advance.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören: if a function is concave/convex and invertible, its inverse function is convex/concave.

Comment: Yes but concave or convex? I did this: $h=r(f(x))$ for $r=g^{-1}$ and $f=1-g$. Then $h^{''}(x)=r^{''}(f(x))f^{'}(x)^2+r^{'}(f(x))f^{''}(x)>0$, so $h$ is convex. Is what I did actually trivial? cannot $f(x)$ change the function from convex to concave?

Comment: okay it seems above, it is not guaranteed to be greater than zero because $f^{''}(x)>0$, $r^{'}(f(x))<0$, and  $r^{''}(f(x))>0$ and $f^{'}(x)^2>0$.